# d3.event is null in a ReactJS + d3JS component

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, system

I'm using **ReactJS, d3JS and ES6** to create an org chart. I can create the chart and see it. But I want to add the zoom behavior to the chart, so I used **d3.behavior.zoom**. I can see the method **zoomed** is called, but the **d3.event** is null.

In my ASP.NET project I made sure that I don't have any reference to **d3.js** other than in the systemJS configuration which many stackoverflow answers mentioned as the issue related to **d3.event** is null.

This is my systemJS configuration:

```
<script>
    System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
    System.config({
        map: {
            'rx': "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.min.js",
            'react': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js',
            'react-dom': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js',
            'd3': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.16/d3.js'
        }
    });
    System.import('../app/app.js');
</script>
```

OrgChart component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Rx from 'rx';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import Person from './person';

class OrgChart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { persons: [] };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON("/js/org-persons.json"));

        source.subscribe(
            function(chart) {
                var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                    .nodeSize([110, 50])
                    .separation(function() {
                        return 1;
                    });

                var nodes = tree.nodes(chart[0]).reverse();

                var links = tree.links(nodes);

                var p = [];

                nodes.forEach(function(node) {
                    fs.push((<Person x={node.x} y={node.y}></Person>));
                }.bind(this));

                this.setState({ person: p });

            }.bind(this)
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var rootX = document.body.clientWidth / 4;
        var rootY = 300;

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", this.zoomed)
            .translate([rootX, rootY]);

        d3.select("#viewport")
            .call(zoom);
    }

    zoomed() {
        d3.select("#viewport").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <svg id='fullTree' width='100%'>
                <g id='viewport'>
                    { this.state.persons }
                </g>
            </svg>
        );
    }
}

export default OrgChart;
```

Comment: Did you resolved it? I have the same problem with d3 v3.x and react 15.3.2. d3.event is always null.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using React, Babel or Webpack and d3.js v4, it looks like you need to import `event` from d3-selection in order to use `d3.event`

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {event as currentEvent} from 'd3-selection';
```

You can now use `currentEvent` the same way you'd use `d3.event`. See https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2733 for more information.

Comment: I had this same problem but using `d3` v3. I had luck with `import {event as currentEvent} from 'd3';` [source](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2814)

Answer (score 5):

If you are importing multiple d3 packages.
these packages have a d3 object accessible which might clash with one another. you have to import them with different names.

```
import d3 from 'd3-selection'
import d3Zoom from 'd3-zoom'
import d3Scale from 'd3-scale'
```

and have a anonymous function for your callback

```
.on("zoom", () => d3.select("#viewport")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
)
```

Comment: why are you importing `import d3Scale from 'd3-scale'`?

Comment: `import d3Scale from 'd3-scale'` was added just as an example. nothing to do with the snippet above.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For some reason, importing `event` from `d3-selection` did not work for me while `import d3 from d3-selection` solves the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try importing d3 like this instead : 
`import d3 from 'd3';`

This issue seems to occur when two occurences of d3 exist in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Quick shot, try this.

```
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", () => d3.select("#viewport").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");)
        .translate([rootX, rootY]);
```

If this works, than following should resolve your issue,

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this))
            .translate([rootX, rootY]);
```

Comment: Can you pass d3 as param to the callback function like .on("zoom", (d3) => d3.select("#viewport").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're doing, but it smells like you're overthinking it. In theory, the zoom behavior changes ranges of scales.

So all you have to do, is base your visualization on two scales - one for `x` coordinates, one for `y` coordinates. Then you tell zoom to change those scales and your visualization changes automagically.

Basically, zooming in just means that `x` and `y` map wider. At `zoom-level = 1` a conceptual coordinate `(0.1, 0.1)` maps to, say, `(10, 10)`. When zoom level changes to 2, that same mapping becomes `(20, 20)`. This creates the impression of zooming in.

Here's some old code of mine that uses this principle to create zooming: https://github.com/Swizec/candidate-bucket-chart/blob/169779e110c8825f4545c71ae5845ff7bad4f1f4/src/BubbleChart.jsx

The React itself is a bit outdated by now, and I haven't had time to extrapolate the zooming into a cleaner example project, but I hope it helps.

Remember to `forceUpdate` because React doesn't know your scales changed.

Comment: I compared my code to yours. It is the same and the calls made at the right API in react. But I get the event in the **d3.event** as null. If you have seen the event in the **d3.event** as not null, this issue may be ReactJS related 1.15 because that's what I use.