# d3.event is null in webpack build

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack

I have a working D3/React/Webpack system where I am trying to reduce the build size by not importing all of D3. So I have a d3Import.js file with:

```
import { select, event } from 'd3-selection';
import { drag } from 'd3-drag';

export default { select: select, drag: drag, event: event };
```

and this is referenced with

```
import d3 from '../../d3Import.js';
```

Everything builds and works fine (there are many more imports than the ones shown above) with the exception of querying the event on e.g. a drag event.

```
onDrag = () => {
    const targetY = d3.event.y;
```

This fails with

**TypeError: _d3Import2.default.event is null**

I have tried using a different name for event as I read a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887428/d3-event-is-null-in-a-reactjs-d3js-component)

```
import { select, event as currentEvent } from 'd3-selection';
```

...but no change. It all used to work with

```
import * as d3 from 'd3;
```

But that seemed to mean an extra 100k or so in bundle.js. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/32

Comment: Thanks Terry. I had a look. [link](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/32#issuecomment-229889310) looks possible. Hope it does not add extra code to the drag event handler - will it be resolved at build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thanks to comment by Terry, I have a solution from [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/32#issuecomment-229889310):

```
onDrag = () => {
   d3.getEvent = () => require("d3-selection").event;
   const targetY = d3.getEvent().y;
}
```