# d3.event is null in modular d3 project

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-modules

> **Note**: I found an answer to this question
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40304080/2928853). The problem is
>   solved; no need for more answers!

I am doing a project with the following structure:

```
root
|
|____js
|     |__index.js
|
|__node_modules
|             |__d3-*
|             
|
|__index.html
|__package.json
```

index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/getlibs"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="detail"></div>
</div>
<!--script type="module" src="./js/index.js"></script> Also tried this method -->

<script>
    System.import('./js/index.js');
</script>
</body>
```

index.js:

```
import {select} from "d3-selection";
import {event as currentEvent} from "d3-selection";
let svg = select('#detail')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500);
        svg.on('click', function() {
            console.log(window.event);
            console.log(currentEvent);
         });
```

And the output is:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 266, screenY: 247, clientX: 266, clientY: 175, …}
null
```

If I use d3 globally through a script tag, referring to it inside the module via `window.d3`, then `d3.event` correctly catches the mouse event. I want to create a modular project and avoid having a global d3 object.

Is that achievable, and if so, how?

Comment: Might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/36887428/215552; sounds very similar.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, the code in this question is my implementation of the top-voted answer for that question. As you can see in the output, `currentEvent` is still null. This does not happen if I hang a `d3` object to `window` which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I don't see an implementation of that entire answer though; there is a `import * as d3 from 'd3';` line in that answer that is not in your question. There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482882/215552) which refers to using `import d3 from 'd3';` and (presumably) using `d3.event`, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40304080/215552) which talks about making `d3` a target to a specific implementation of `d3` (in your case, presumably `import d3 from 'd3-selection'` would be sufficient).

Comment: @jrook please provide additional details including the version of d3 and SystemJS and your SystemJS configuration if you have one

Comment: Sorry. You are correct I misread

Comment: @HereticMonkey, please provide your comment as an answer and I will accept it. I have another question if you care to answer though: how come I can import `d3` from `d3-selection` even though there is no declaration of its export in `d3-selection`'s `index.js` ??

Comment: Well, I'd rather close the question as a duplicate of the other question, since it's basically the same, and my comment is basically a recapitulation of the answers from that question, meaning I'd be stealing rep from those answerers. However, since it has a bounty, I can't close it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I don't mind the question being labeled as a duplicate. But I went through all those questions multiple times before posting a question myself and still couldn't figure it out.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40304080/2928853) works and I upvoted it. Still the question is asked in the context of React and people may be confused because of it. Note that I wanted to avoid using `d3` as a module and only use its submodules so I didn't consider many of the answers in the questions you refer to.

Comment: I do think it is a duplicate. You may want to consider adding a comment to that answer about having to use `d3.event` to capture the event rather than just importing `event`. I'm guessing they're using the `d3` global variable to capture the latest event. Not a great design, but then I'm not the author of a widely-used library :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, ok, what should I do about this question? Apparently, I can't cancel the bounty!

Comment: I'd just let the bounty expire; there haven't been that many views. You might want to add a note to the top of the question about its duplicate nature though, to dissuade rep-hungry answerers.