# ES6 export of a script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using D3 v5 in React and has a visualization that uses v3.  I'm using npm modules for the v5 but for v3, I'm trying to import D3 to be used in that visualization.

In my component I have:

```
import * as d3 from './lib/d3/v3/d3';
```

and in the d3 folder's d3.js, the minified v3 d3 script:

```
const d3 = !function(){function n(n){return n&&(n.ownerDocument||n....

export default d3;
```

butI get the following error:

Failed to compile.

```
./src/components/d3/NetworkTopology/D3_NetworkTopology.js
Attempted import error: 'behavior' is not exported from './lib/d3/v3/d3' (imported as 'd3').
```

NetworkTopology.js:

```
  ...
  const zoom = d3.behavior
    .zoom()
```

"behavior" was removed in v4 so to me it looks like this is pulling the D3 V5 version instead of V3.  How can I set this up to use both versions of D3?

I changed the import to:

```
import d3 from './lib/d3/v3/d3';
```

but got these compile errors:
Failed to compile.

./src/components/d3/NetworkTopology/lib/d3/v3/d3.js

```
  Line 1:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

and I get the same error with the original `import * as d3 from './lib/d3/v3/d3';` combined with removing the const and export in the d3.js (just use the original minified file).

Comment: I am not sure if [a question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529544/d3-event-is-null-in-modular-d3-project) helps. Try not exporting d3 and just use it because it seems to be a global variable for all d3 components.

Comment: @jrook, I tried that but get a bunch of compile errors (updated the question at the end.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the previous answers got me around the original error in the top portion of my question, by using:

> import d3 from './lib/d3/v3/d3

, I ended up getting ES-Lint errors, which I got around by adding

> /* eslint-disable */

Howevever, I then got an error caused by Babel inserting "use strict" on the D3 minified code.  Since Create React App doesn't allow modification of the Babel configuration without ejecting the application, I was stuck.  I thought about putting in a script in the template or an AJAX call to get the D3 script from a CDN, but I'm not sure it would have worked with the two D3 versions in the same app.

What eventually worked was the following.  I cloned the earlier version of D3 into a directory at my app's root, then I modified the name in its package.json to be 'd3-v3' and renamed the directory to 'd3-v3'.  Scoped npm package naming would have been preferable for the package name.

Then I did a:

```
npm install file:./d3-v3
```

From my React component I used the following for D3 v3

```
import * as d3 from 'd3-v3';
```

and for v5 used:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with the versions of d3. Your problem is that your script with the minified library has a single `export default d3` (an export with the name `default` bound to a constant with the value of `d3`), while your component does a namespace `import * as d3` which means that `d3` will be a module object containing all exports - in your case, only the `default` one. So `d3.default.behaviour` could work. But you should just change your import to not use namespace objects but instead have the single value imported directly:

```
import d3 from './lib/d3/v3/d3';
// which is short for
import { default as d3 } from './lib/d3/v3/d3';
```

Comment: I switched it but I got a compile error now (question updated at the end.)

Comment: @user994165 Not sure about that, but it doesn't seem to be related to the imports. Might be a problem with running a linter on a minified script?

Answer (score 0):

you should update

```
    import d3 from './lib/d3/v3/d3';
```

Comment: I switched it but I got a compile error now (question updated at the end.)

Comment: Please support your answer with some explanation.