# Getting error while importing D3.js library in my React.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-redux, components

I'm facing an issue regarding importing the d3.js libraries properly in my react.js app. I am using **import * as d3 from 'd3'** to import everything and save it to d3 namespace but getting an error called - **Cannot read property 'category20' of undefined**. Any help regarding the issue ?

Click here to see the => [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9swa5l)

```
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import donut from "./d3.donut.jsx";
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class PieCharts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;
    //let PieData=this.props.data;
    var getData = function() {
      var size = 4;
      var data = {};
      var text = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data["data-" + (i + 1)] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        text += "data-" + (i + 1) + " = " + data["data-" + (i + 1)] + "<br/>";
      }
      d3.select("#data").html(text);
      return data;
    };

    var chart = donut()
      .$el(d3.select("#" + self.props.id))
      .data(getData())
      .render();
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.props.data)
    return (
      <div>
        <div id={this.props.id} />
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.clickActivity}>
          Simulate
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<PieCharts />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I asked a [rather similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529544/d3-event-is-null-in-modular-d3-project) a while back. Try:`import d3 from 'd3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its syntax error. You are using d3 v5 so you need to follow the updated syntax

```
Use d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20) instead of d3.scale.category20().
Use d3.pie instead of d3.layout.pie
Use d3.arc() instead of d3.svg.arc()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh. My bad, as I didn't check. So It was actually happening as the version of **D3** automatically got updated to **5.7.0** from **3.5.17**.